# Website Animation Background

Tags: jquery, html, css

Few days ago, I visited one of my favorite movie website

And I stunned when I saw it.

http://www.waltermitty.com/about

I am curious to know, how they doing this kind of animation background effect?

Is that Parallax.js?

Comment: can be done perfectly with css

Comment: @avrilalejandro, you mean by using transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to burst your bubble, but it's actually playing videos in WebM format.

Here's an example video: http://www.waltermitty.com/img/videos/Street_Mitty.webm

Comment: That WebM can create by our own? And also cut out from video?

Comment: The videos were probably created with After Effects or something similar.

Comment: I would try it out. Thank you so much.